# Multiple mt_rand in same script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a random comment script for Wordpress that I've been using as a widget. It has worked fine for showing just one comment but now I need it to show three. I tried just adding new variables and output copying the existing code but the possibility of it generating the same comment multiple times is a lot more often than I thought it would be. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's the original code for showing just one comment:

```
<div style="width:276px;margin:0 15px">
<h2>Testimonials</h2>
<div style="background:rgba(65, 115, 148, 0.3);border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;height:265px;border:1px solid #ddd;box-shadow:0 0 3px #fff;padding:5px;overflow-y:auto">

<?php
   $post_id = 276;  // Put the 'testimonials' id here
   $comments = get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve");
   if ($comments) {
     $ndx = mt_rand(2,sizeof($comments)) - 1;
     $comment = $comments[$ndx];
?>

<p style="margin-bottom:20px">
<span style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><?php echo get_avatar($comment->comment_author_email, 48, $default, $alt ); ?></span>
    <?php
        if (empty($comment->comment_author)){echo "$comment->comment_author";}
        else{echo "<a href='$comment->comment_author_url'>$comment->comment_author</a>";}
    ?>
 - <?php echo "$comment->comment_date"; ?><br />
<?php echo "$comment->comment_content"; ?></p>
<span style="float:right;margin-right:3px;"><?php echo "$comment1->extra_sitename"; ?></span>

<?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another approach.
Lets say you construct an array of available comments ids.

```
$commIDs = array(4,34,56,76,100); // comment id from database
```

Then you can use array_rand() to get 3 random ids of this array.

```
$choosenIDs = array_rand($commIDs, 3);
```

Then you can get your data from db based on selected ids.
Is this close to what you look for?

**EDIT:** 2nd solution
You can get 3 random records directly from database.

```
Select field FROM table WHERE field2='$value' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we ["unset"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) the chosen random value from the array, we can select another one without fear of duplication. Note that I'm starting `mt_rand` from zero and subtracting `1` from `sizeof`.

```
<?php
$pid = get_the_ID();
$comments = get_comments("post_id=$pid&status=approve");
if ($comments) {       
    $ndx = mt_rand( 0, sizeof( $comments ) -1 );
    $comment = $comments[$ndx];
    array_splice( $comments, $ndx, 1 );

    $ndx = mt_rand( 0, sizeof( $comments ) -1 );
    $comment = $comments[$ndx];
    array_splice( $comments, $ndx, 1 );

    $ndx = mt_rand( 0, sizeof( $comments ) -1 );
    $comment = $comments[$ndx];
    // array_splice( $comments, $ndx, 1 ); // only needed if you'll keep showing comments
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't seem to get it working. I'm still learning PHP and not very good at it. I tried the code as supplied but it just loads blank. I then tried to echo the fields as before but still nothing. Also, could you point me in the direction of some manuals or tutorials that might explain why you are subtracting 1 from sizeof? I saw that the other code was doing it as well but I haven't a clue what it does.

Comment: I've made a small update so it looks like your code, hpefuly easier to adapt. The -1 is because arrays start at zero, so an array with 3 elements (length==3) is: `$arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]`